# Practical guide on machine learning for developers?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Machine learning seems to be a buzzword on startups, but as a traditional developer dealing mainly on MySQL, Python/PHP, Javascript, etc, I cannot find any really helpful tutorial online that can get me started on using machine learning techniques to enhance existing web projects.

So what I have in mind is like

```
- categorizing/tagging user submitted post automatically
- provide personalized recommendation
```

At the risk of being close as non constructive, might I ask here: would there be a "Hello World" kind of projects, or basic use-cases that help introducing machine learning techniques to practical programmers? Or at least some guides as to how to get started on this track?

Comment: Unfortunately still not constructive, or, the new reason, "asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource" (see the [help/on-topic]).

Answer (score 1):

Although many would recommend [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/OLD/ESLII_print4.pdf), by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman, I feel the following resources more suited for people with a programming background rather than a mathematical background:

- [Machine Learning for Hackers](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018483.do),  Drew Conway and John Myles White, O'Reilly, 2012
- [Algorithms for the Intelligent Web](http://www.manning.com/marmanis/) Haralambos Marmanis and Dmitry Babenko, Manning, 2009

To really get hands on, choose a language and find a machine learning library in that language, along with an accompanying tutorial. For instance [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/), or [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) for Java, [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) for Python, etc.

Also, PyGotham2011 features a [video tutorial](http://pyvideo.org/video/484/pygotham-2011--machine-learning-for-web-developer) on developing machine learning-based features for web development.

Answer (score 1):

There's quiet a nice, practical hands-on book which might give you some basic insights on what is going on:

Collective Intelligence - Building smart Web2.0 applications

ISBN-10: 0596529325
ISBN-13: 978-0596529321

It is using Python as example language, but I think it should give you some ideas.

Regarding Recommendations, there is also a good Introduction to Mahout Recommenders:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Recommender+Documentation

Mahout also has the capabilities of doing clustering / categorizing texts, so it's worth to have a look into this machine learning library.